# Do not move the map when clicked on a marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

When I click on a marker on map which is on the edges of the map, the map adjusts(moves) to show the info window completely.

Is there a way to stop doing that?

Because I have to call `clearMarkers()` function to remove all the markers from the map when the map is moved( or say the center changes).

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gMap, 'center_changed', function(){
      clearMarkers();
});
```

so the markers disappears and re-appear.

Comment: Why do you have to clear all of the markers when the map is moved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible by disabling the autoPan option in your infowindow declaration like so:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: 'yourContent',
  disableAutoPan: true
```

});

This should solve your issue for you. API reference available [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions).